# best practice for get a block by id in *.phtml template in 2022 year?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, phtml

Can you help me figure out which best practices to use for get block template by id in phtml file?
*thanks everyone*

> if you need some info please send comment

---

okay, try it:

- i created a block in admin panel with id bottom-content and the block will be show in frontend

- i trying to get block template in *.phtml with the code:

```php
<?php 

echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
    ->setBlockId('bottom-content')
    ->toHtml(); 
?>
```

> *but i know that is not best practice. sure best practice is it call block in *.xml*

- then my code look this:

```xml
<referenceBlock name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="bottom.content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="bottom.content">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">bottom.content</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceBlock>
```

- And in this case my *.phtml look this:

```php
<?= $this->getChildHtml('bottom-content'); ?>
```

**But when i open a site i observe this error:**

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): An element with a "bottom.content" ID already exists.

##### How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

As \Magento\Cms\Block\Block is deprecated, you should use the \Magento\Cms\Block\BlockByIdentifier

Example in phtml

```
<?= $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(BlockByIdentifier::class)
            ->setData('identifier', 'return_page_description')
            ->toHtml();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring 2 blocks with the same name, so you face that error.

To fix it, replace your XML file with the following:

```
<referenceBlock name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="bottom.content">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">bottom-content</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

And you also declare the wrong value for `block_id` argument and call the wrong block name in the phtml file.
Replace your code in phtml file to call the call with the following:

```
<?= $this->getChildHtml('bottom.content'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code in your Phtml file

```
<?php
        echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
            ->setBlockId('set_identifier') // you can set block identifier you want here
            ->toHtml();
        ?>
```